# Jmeter - Controlling iteration using pacing time

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm new to jmeter so i need help in controlling the iteration after a specific amount of seconds.

For example,
I'm running 5 threads in 1 iteration

- Scenario 1: I need the iteration to stop after 300 seconds. If the threads are still running, i need to stop their execution and start the next iteration
- Scenario 2: If the iteration is completed in T seconds & T<300, then I need to delay for (300-T) seconds before the next iteration can start.

Are there any existing elements in Jmeter which can be used to achieve this or a groovy function is required to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

1. Scenario 1 is partially achievable using [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller). It won't stop the execution of running threads, but it will start the next iteration as soon as the thread finishes execution of the current request. Consider defining reasonable timeouts
2. Scenario 2 is achievable using [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy scripting](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy).

   - Record iteration start time in the iteration start using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler):

     ```
     vars.putObject('iterationStart', System.currentTimeMillis())
     ```
   - Add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler as the last Sampler in your "iteration"
   - Add [JSR223 Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Timer) as a child of the Flow Control Action Sampler and put the following code there:

     ```
     def delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - vars.getObject('iterationStart')

     if (delta < 300000) {
       return 300000 - delta
     }
     ```
   - Add a [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) as a child of the Flow Control Action sampler to act as a rendez-vous point for the 5 threads